# Yii urlManager rewrite and route when url contains 'www'

Tags: php, html, url, yii

I'm using the 'www' subdomain as a sort of start menu from which a user can select from multiple links leading to other areas *(subdomains)* of the website. *(Ex. http://www.example.com >> (click Dog link) >> go to http://dogs.example.com)*. I short, I need Yii urlManager to do two things when the url contains 'www':

**(1) Rewrite the Url:** 
If the url contains 'www' lets remove any extras from the url so that only 'http://www.example.com' remains. *(Ex. if a user types in http://www.example.com/page1 we correct/rewrite to http://www.example.com)*

**(2) Route to Action:** 
If the url contains 'www', lets route to a specific controller/action to render the menu. *(Ex. http://www.example.com routes to site/menu)*.

How to do this with Yii urlManager? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try redirect all www. conatins requests to main page like this (.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```